What COTS drone can be programmed and accept sensor inputs for autonomous flight?
I'm mentoring high school students this summer on a navigation project involving a drone. I'd like to find a drone that can take input from a sensor (in this case it would be a photodiode) that I will attach to the drone body, and upload an algorithm to its hardware to use the sensor's input to determine its location and make course corrections.
I have never flown a drone before, but I did just pick up the Part 107 certification to supervise the students. I have a couple of models available to me to borrow from my lab, one of which is a DJI mini SE and the other might be a DJI Tello.
I will purchase a drone if I need to, but I don't even know where to begin trying to search for something that has the ability to be programmed and accept sensor inputs. Does anyone in the community know a good place to start looking, or even what to search for? Thanks!
